# IF OR/AND Formula Field

Tags: formula

I would like to be able to choose between two scenarios but I cant quite seem to get the formula right.

I've read through questions but can't seem to apply. It is very simple what I need I'm sure but I need to know the best way to approach:

```
OR (IF (AND(Amountdue = 0, order <> 3) , "CLEAR", "OUSTANDING"),

IF ( order = 3, "SUSPENDED", "ERROR")
)
```

If nesting is there a rule of thumb to follow? More resources I can read that are clear and super simple.

Comment: Try this  :  IF(AND(Amountdue = 0, order <> 3) , 'CLEAR', 'OUSTANDING', 
IF ( order = 3, "SUSPENDED", "ERROR"))

Comment: can you describe the business logic that you want to achieve with the formula?

Comment: If the related record has been stamped with Order = 3 then it should show SUSPENDED this will override if there is an amount due. If its not SUSPENDED then display if there is an amount due as OUTSTANDING and 0 in the amount due as PAID.

Comment: @N.B. thank you though this is the error that I get: 
 Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 4

Comment: @user48743, I checked it. Could you see if this works :  IF(AND(Amountdue = 0, order <> 3) , 'CLEAR', 
IF(order = 3, 'SUSPENDED',
IF(OR(Amountdue <> 0, order = 3), 'OUSTANDING',
IF(Amountdue = 0 , 'PAID', 'ERROR' ))))

Comment: @N.B. that seems to do the trick.  realised as I read your formula that there were only 3 possible scenarios and was able to shorten to:

IF(AND(Amountdue = 0, Status <> 3) , 'CLEAR', 

IF(Status = 3, 'CANCELLED','OUTSTANDING'))

Comment: @user48743, glad you got it to work. :)